# Django rearrange objects inside querySet by index

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-views, django-queryset

In my application i have table called "Task". In this table there is a field called priority with a restricted choice of ("High", "Medium", "Low"). I have ordered these by priority which have an order of: High, Low, Medium when i would like the order to be High, Medium, Low. How could i swap
Low and Medium inside the querySet around?

views.py:

```
tasks = Tasks.objects.values("priority").annotate(count=Count("priority"))
```

output:

```
<QuerySet [{'priority': 'High', 'count': 3}, {'priority': 'Low', 'count': 3}, {'priority': 'Medium', 'count': 3}]>
```

desired output:

```
<QuerySet [{'priority': 'High', 'count': 3}, {'priority': 'Medium', 'count': 3}, {'priority': 'Low', 'count': 3}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by an annotation, so you can add an annotation that sets a particular value using `Case` and `When` that would suitably re-order your queryset:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Count, Value

tasks = Tasks.objects.annotate(re_order=Case(
        When(priority="High", then=Value(3)),
        When(priority="Medium", then=Value(1)),
        When(priority="Low", then=Value(2)),
        default=Value(0),
     )
).order_by('re_order').values("priority").annotate(count=Count("status"))
```

You could use a dict and `**` unpacking to make this a bit more DRY.